# Output from `kable()` combined with text as character vector and print table

Tags: r, function, knitr, kable

I have the following RMarkdown Document (also [here as a gist](https://gist.github.com/rkrug/fcb145f5ebf27ded865cca943332dbf6))

[image]

results in this

[image]

I would like to use the function `fun()` to create a proper table as from the first code chunk.

I thought that `format = "markdown` and `results = "asis"` should do the job, but apparently not.

What Am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your goal, but the problem is pasting together a `knitr_kable` with some text. If you simply replace your definition of `fun` with `fun <- function (x) {
  cat("Some text");
  knitr::kable(x, format = "markdown")
}` then the function call produces the text and the table correctly.

Comment: True. But I need the additional text as  am iterating through a list of objects which contains a header (the text) and a table which I both want to have in the report.

Comment: But my code produces the additional text before the table. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Sorry - I was in the train. I misread your comment. I will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Due to unknown reasons, I have to `print()` the result from `kable()` (I think because they are returned invisibly). So the function which works **perfectly** is: `fun <- function (x) { cat("Some text"); print(knitr::kable(x, format = "markdown")) }`. If you put this into an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.